# How do I create a directory from hook_install of a module in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, hook, drupal-modules, absolute-path, drupal-7

Actually, I know how to create a directory = mkdir.
However, I need to pass it a full absolute path in the server, and I don't know how to get the relevant path in hook_install.
I tried using base_path(), but it returned '/'.

The path I want is sites/default/files (inside "files" I create the directory).

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try `mkdir('sites/default/files/yourdir')`? If so, where does that create the directory? If not, why not?

Relative directory names are resolved based on the working directory. The working directory in Drupal is usually the directory in which your `install.php` and `index.php` is located.

Comment: I just did mkdir('sites/default/files/mydir') as you said, and it worked as I wanted. Thanks

Comment: this will not work if the module is not used in the default site. Drupal 7 is multi site ready and this solution makes assumptions that it will be working on the default site.

Answer (score 9):

Please use the proper APIs.

```
$directory = file_default_scheme() . '://yourdir';
file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);
```